# LIKE clause problems

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm working on a small mobile web app. I have a query that has a `LIKE` clause. For example:

```sql
SELECT from posts WHERE (title LIKE '%car%') or (content LIKE '%car%');
```

The problem I'm having is variables in javascript have single quotes around their values. So I get the following:

```sql
SELECT from posts WHERE (title LIKE '%'car'%') or (content LIKE '%'car'%');
```

Actual string I'm building this way:

```
"SELECT from posts WHERE (title LIKE '%" + client.escape(input) + "%') or (content LIKE '%" + client.escape(input) + "%');"
```

Comment: Are you running this query from Node? Which mysql module are you using?

Comment: put the `%` signs in your input before you call escape.

Comment: `SELECT from` doesn't look like valid mysql syntax either.

Comment: You're right, just tried locally and `connection.scape()` doesn't escape single quotes, weird.

Comment: I suggest looking at where those quotes are coming from.  Your generalization about javascript simply putting them there is incorrect.

Comment: It can be double quotes as well, as it is valid for JS and JSON have to be with double quotes in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enclosing `'`s are added by the escape function automatically, so move the `%`s to inside the variable and escape it, and remove the `'`s from your query:

```
input = client.escape('%' + input + '%'); //=== "'%escaped_input%'"
client.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (title LIKE " + input + ") or (content LIKE " + input + ")", function(err, results) {
     // ...
});
```

### [*Reference -  Escaping query values*](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values)

Alternatively, you should be able to use the emulated prepared statements syntax as well:

```
input = '%' + input + '%';
client.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (title LIKE ?) or (content LIKE ?)", [input, input], function(err, results) {
     // ...
});
```

This will perform something similar to `sprintf`, replacing the `?` placeholders by the properly escaped items (internally using the same `escape` method as above) from second argument array, in the order they were passed - the placeholders' order corresponds to the array items' order.

---

Side-note: I assume you've oversimplified the query removing all the fields from `SELECT` statement, remember to select at least a field or all of them (`*`) otherwise it is not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: Yeah I normally would use the emulated prepared statements, but in this case I have multiple inputs to compare using the LIKE clause. Thank you so much for your help.